# How to fail maven build if annotation used?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-plugin, static-code-analysis

I want to forbid usage of some annotations in a project. Specially @SneakyThrows annotation from [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html). 
One way to do this is to fail while building maven artifact.
Are there some existing plugins to reach this?

I think it is possible to achive using static code analyzers like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). But I don't want to write new rule for it.

Also it is interesting if exists such plugins for gradle?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>target/**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <regex>false</regex>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>@SneakyThrows</token>
                        <value>@@@@ I-DONT-THINK-SO @@@@</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I use this actually to kill warnings on generated sources by annotating every class/enum/interface with `@SurpressWarnings("all")`

Comment: Is this a pure text replacement approach? Does it produce understandable error messages? Does it change the files in the user directory?

Comment: Therefore build will fail at compilation phase. Ok, it should work, but this plugin doesn't fail build and not produce any message errors. Anyway, thanks!